# NodeJs TCP server not handling requests consistently

Tags: node.js, http, tcp, connection

I am trying to implement a TCP server. But it stops taking requests randomly.

I sometimes get following error and I sometimes get the right object that I am sending.

What might cause this?

**Browser error:**

```
The connection was reset

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

**Browser success: (which is the *config.tubes* object in the server)**

```
{"A":{"key":1,"status":2},"B":{"key":2,"status":0},"C":{"key":3,"status":0}}
```

**Server code**

```
net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer();

PORT = 5000;
ADDRESS = '127.0.0.1';

var server = net.createServer(onClientConnected);
server.listen(PORT);

function onClientConnected(socket) {
  console.log(`New client: ${socket.remoteAddress}:${socket.remotePort}`);
  socket.write(JSON.stringify(config.tubes));
  socket.destroy();
}

console.log(`Server started at: ${ADDRESS}:${PORT}`);
```

Comment: I made an experiment but cannot reproduce the problem. The connection to the server is always successful.

Answer (score 0):

```
socket.destroy();
```

should be

```
socket.end();
```